# Differences between anime and manga versions of Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic

Tags: magi

I watched Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic and want to pick up the manga starting from anime end. If manga and anime are too different, I might read skipped chapters.
How different are then anime and manga versions? Do I need to read it to cover the whole story?

Comment: The anime is alot higher paced. alot more happening and skippin minor events that are in the manga.

Comment: I think you should read from the beginning. Because the anime mixed up a lot of the chapters and basically you'll just miss out on some chapters and extra details that was not shown in the anime :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're about the same, but the anime doesn't always follow the manga's plot.

If you're new to the series and want to know where to start, go with the manga first, then watch the anime, because the anime is based on the manga.

If you want to know the differences, I have spotted a few changes in season 1 that differ from the manga. The examples below are from chapter 120:

> In the anime, Alibaba became a Dark Metal Vessel user or Dark Djinn Equip near the end of season 1, which isn't part of the manga.
>
>  Another change is that Hakuryuu got his arm **cut off** in a sword fight trying to protect Alibaba, instead of falling off after the Zagan arc in the manga.